# Send txt file to printer with Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, printing, text-files

I have a sub that creates a .txt file and I want to print it in the default printer. How can I achieve this in VBA?

I think I need to call the ShellExecute API Function, but I did not find the correct sintax for that.

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

I found a code that do the trick:

```
Option Explicit 

Declare Function apiShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _ 
ByVal hwnd As Long, _ 
ByVal lpOperation As String, _ 
ByVal lpFile As String, _ 
ByVal lpParameters As String, _ 
ByVal lpDirectory As String, _ 
ByVal nShowCmd As Long) _ 
As Long 

Public Sub PrintFile(ByVal strPathAndFilename As String) 

    Call apiShellExecute(Application.hwnd, "print", strPathAndFilename, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0) 

End Sub 

Sub Test() 

    PrintFile ("C:\Test.pdf") 

End Sub
```

Comment: hi.  but if I want to print pdf file without open the file?(something like openAfterPublish/print:=False)